# Why can I not catch my exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I have following function that catches the system-exception of a ComObject and throws my own exception off:

```
int TReader::ExecSQL(...) {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (Comobj::EOleException& e) {
    throw myDBError("TReader::Open", "TReader", e.Message);
  }
// ...   
}
```

I can not catch my own exception, getting always "Exception unknown!"! Why?

```
void main() {
  try {
    ExecSQL(...);
  } catch(myDBError& e) {
    log(e.Message);
  } catch(...) {
    log("Exception unknown!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* a `Comobj::EOleExceptio` exception is thrown?

Comment: And check (we cannot see that in provided code) that `myDBError` is derived from `std::exception`

Comment: @VolAnd And, why would it need to be derived from `std::exception`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think you are right, for C++ it is not needed.

Answer (score 7):

Use `catch(const myDBError& e) {` instead.

An anonymous temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference, so a `throw` will not be intercepted at the current catch site.

Comment: I have written a test. The thrown exception is captured in "catch(myDbError)"! The original exception is raised from a DLL! Now I am going to test this scenario...

Comment: Exceptions from a DLL works as well. I think I have an other unknown Problem... Thank you all so far!

Answer (score -1):

If `try-catch` block generates not `Comobj::EOleException`, but something else, that may be problem.
Also check, maybe `myDBError` constructor generates another exception, with another type :-)
That would be funniest explanation, why you can't catch `myDBError`, but still catch something :-)